# Как обратиться к указателю в структуре?

Tags: c++, указатели, struct

Имется структура:

```
struct _nvr
{
  char ip_nvr[50];
  char log[50];
  char passwd[50];
  char ip_cam[20][50];
  char id_cam[16][10];
  LONG lUserID;
  NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 struDeviceInfo; //the info get when login
  NET_DVR_WORKSTATE_V40 *pStruWorkStateV40;
  NET_DVR_GETWORKSTATE_COND struWorkStateCond;
  DWORD dwList;
  int flag;
};

_nvr nvr[30] = {};
```

1. Как можно обратится к данной переменной `*pStruWorkStateV40`?
2. Можно ли ее проинициализировать в структуре:

   ```
   NET_DVR_WORKSTATE_V40 *pStruWorkStateV40 = new NET_DVR_WORKSTATE_V40;
   ```

Comment: На будущее рекомендую ознакомиться с тем, как создать [mcve] и приводить в вопросе только существенную часть. В данном случае множество лишних полей можно было бы выкинуть из демонстрационного кода и имя типу дать по-проще.

Answer (score 3):

Если к самому значению - то

```
*nvr[i].pStruWorkStateV40
```

Если к какому-то полю `NET_DVR_WORKSTATE_V40` - то

```
nvr[i].pStruWorkStateV40->field_name
```

Comment: тогда получается что если я использую NET_DVR_WORKSTATE_V40 из сторонней библиотеки в структуре, то она уже не сможет обращаться к полям, потому как библиотеку нужно изменять pStruWorkStateV40->field_name    ?

Comment: @JTAG Поясните, не совсем понятен смысл вопроса. Кто она и почему не сможет?

Comment: Ну вы вместо field_name пишете имя нужного поля, я же их не знаю...

Comment: Вот к примеру в закрытой библиотеке  будет доступ к полю такой: pStruWorkStateV40.field_name. Если я эту переменную у себя помещю в структуру, то к ней нужно обращаться вот так - pStruWorkStateV40->field_name. И библиотека не сможет это сделать.

Comment: Ощущение какого-то сюра. Какая бы ни была закрытая библиотека, тип должен быть описан. Обращение pStruWorkStateV40.field_name возможно, если  pStruWorkStateV40 не указатель, а переменная структуры или (в С++) ссылка. У вас в вашей структуре она описана как **указатель**. Обращение через указатель к полю структуры выполняется или с помощью ptr->field, или (*ptr).field.

Answer (score 0):

К указателям в структурах обращаются так же как и к любым другим членам данных:

```
имя_экземпляра.имя_поля_данных
```

Это базовая информация, которая даётся в самом начале любого учебника/курса по языку. Без таких знаний просто невозможно создать что-то минимально осмысленное.

> Можно ли ее проинициализировать в структуре?

Инициализация нестатического члена в момент определения структуры возможна в c++, начиная с c++11:

```
struct S {
   T* var = new T();
};
```

В [c](/questions/tagged/c) и более ранних c++ стандартах такая инициализация невозможна. Требуется создавать конструктор (с++) или делать это в некоторой функции инициализации (с).

Answer (score 0):

У вас объявлен массив структур

```
_nvr nvr[30] = {};
```

Чтобы обратиться к члену данных какого-либо элемента этого массива, вы должны выбрать элемент массива с помощью оператора индексирования. Например,

```
nvr[i]
```

где i - это некоторое значение индекса в диапазоне `[0, 30)`, и применить оператор обращения к члену данных класса `.`. Например,

```
nvr[i].pStruWorkStateV40
```

Теперь вы этому члену данных можете присвоить некоторое значение. Например,

```
nvr[i].pStruWorkStateV40 = new NET_DVR_WORKSTATE_V40;
```

В этом случае член данных, представляющий из себя указатель и заданный выражением `nvr[i].pStruWorkStateV40`, будет указывать на выделенный памяти объект.

Чтобы присвоить некоторое значение этому объекту, вы должны разыменовать этот указатель, используя оператор разыменования `*`  . Например,

```
*nvr[i].pStruWorkStateV40 = SomeValue;
```